# Converting netcore2.2 -> netstandard2: The runcommand property is not defined

Tags: visual-studio, .net-standard

I am in the process of converting my `netcore2.2` app to `netstandard2.0;net472`.

Here is my main project's `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="JWT" Version="5.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="2.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="swashbuckle.aspnetcore" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\mvaasa.repository\mvaasa.repository.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\mvaasa.services\mvaasa.services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is my `Application Settings`:

[image]

Whenever I try and `Start Debugging (IIS Express)`, I get the following error popup:

[image]

How do I set this?

**Update**

I have tried setting the `OutputType` to `Exe` as follow:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

Comment: I think the problem is you can't output `Exe` when targeting .NET Standard. You have to output a library.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/833#issuecomment-440228858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Standard is not a target framework that will generate runnable assemblies. Target .NET Core instead to be able to run on an actual runtime.

Targeting `netstandard2.0` is only useful for libraries, not for programs that you want to run.

When you target multiple frameworks, also make sure you pass the expected runtime to run on:

```
dotnet run -f netcoreapp2.2
```